# Почему в моём коде выдает "warning C6385: Чтение недопустимых данных"?

Tags: c++, c, warning

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <malloc.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int **p;
    int i, j;
    int  M, N;
    char s = 'n';
    while (s != 'Y' && s != 'y')
    {
        printf("\nEnter the number of rows in the array M = \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &M);
        printf("\nEnter the number of columns in the array N= \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &N);
        if ((p = (int**)calloc(N, sizeof(int*))) == 0)
        {
            printf("Memory allocation failure *p \n");
            exit(1);
        }

        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            if ((p[j] = (int*)calloc(N, sizeof(int))) == 0)
            {
                printf("Memory allocation failure  *p[] \n");
                exit(1);
            }

        printf(" Array p[i][j]:\n\n");
        for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                p[i][j] = rand() % (M*N); // 36
                printf(" %3d ", p[i][j]); // 37
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n\n");

        int K;
        printf("\nEnter a number of column to delete K = \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &K);
        for (i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
            for (j = K - 1; j < N - 1; ++j)
            {
                p[i][j] = p[i][j + 1];
                j == K - 1; // 50
            }
        }
        printf(" Array p[i][j]:\n\n");
        for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < N - 1; j++)
            {
                printf(" %5d ", p[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            free(p[j]);
        free(p);
        printf("Close program \n Y - Yes N - No \n");
        s = _getch();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
При
 j == K - 1; // 50
 Выдаёт
[image]
При этом код работает идеально

А если стереть
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

67 - просто не использутся значение `_getch()`

48 - у вас вижу выход за пределы массива: `p[i][j + 1]`, при том, что `j` может достигать значения `N-1`.

Еще у вас странное выделение памяти -

```
    if ((p = (int**)calloc(M, sizeof(int*))) == 0)
```

для `M` указателей, но вы выделяете память для них `N` раз:

```
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        if ((p[j] = (int*)calloc(N, sizeof(int))) == 0)
```